# My GLJPanel display() method takes too much time to run

Tags: java, jogl, display

Here is my problem. I am using JOGL library to create a 3D game. Until now everything were working, but a problem occured. I use a while loop which only repeats `gljpanel.display();`. The problem is that this method sleeps around 4 seconds before executing the `display(GLAutoDrawable glad)` method of my panel, causing a very low and unbearable framerate. I just want to know what could make this method sleep. Here is the code with which I make the GLJPanel work:

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static Panel panel = new Panel();
    private static keyListener klistener = new keyListener();
    private static mouseListener mlistener = new mouseListener();
    private static mouseWheelListener mwlistener = new mouseWheelListener();
    public int[] screenSize = new int[] {getToolkit().getScreenSize().width, getToolkit().getScreenSize().height};

    public void init() { //called firstly
        setTitle("Title");
        setBounds(0, 0, screenSize[0], screenSize[1]);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addKeyListener(klistener);
        addMouseListener(mlistener);
        addMouseWheelListener(mwlistener);

        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    public void trame() { //called secondly
        while (true)
            panel.display();
    }
}
```

and here is my GLJPanel:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import BasicModels.*;
import LivingBeings.Player;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Panel extends GLJPanel implements GLEventListener {

    public static int[] mouse = new int[2];

    public Panel() {
        super();
        this.initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        this.addGLEventListener(this);
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
        GL2 gl2 = glad.getGL().getGL2();
        gl2.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl2.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl2.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl2.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
    }

    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glad) {}

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
        System.out.println("test"); //printed around 4 seconds after "panel.display();" 
        GL2 gl2 = glad.getGL().getGL2();
        GLU glu = new GLU();

        gl2.glViewport(0, 0, Main.frame.screenSize[0], Main.frame.screenSize[1]);

        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();

        glu.gluPerspective(45, (double) Main.frame.screenSize[0] / (double) Main.frame.screenSize[1], 0.1, 100.0);

        Camera.refresh(5, 5, 15, true);

        Point target = Camera.pos.add(Camera.target);
        glu.gluLookAt(Camera.pos.x, Camera.pos.y, Camera.pos.z, target.x, target.y, target.z, 0, 1, 0);

        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();
        gl2.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        setOpaque(false);

        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
        if (Light.activeLights[0] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);
        if (Light.activeLights[1] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);
        if (Light.activeLights[2] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT2);
        if (Light.activeLights[3] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT3);
        if (Light.activeLights[4] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT4);
        if (Light.activeLights[5] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT5);
        if (Light.activeLights[6] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT6);
        if (Light.activeLights[7] != null) gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT7);

        gl2.glPolygonMode(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_FILL);

        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
        gl2.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        Drawer3D.draw(gl2);

        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl2.glPushMatrix();
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();
        glu.gluOrtho2D(0, Main.frame.screenSize[0], Main.frame.screenSize[1], 0);
        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl2.glPushMatrix();
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();

        Drawer2D.draw(gl2);

        gl2.glPopMatrix();
        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl2.glPopMatrix();

        synchronized (Keys.loadingWorldKey) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Player.players.size(); i++)
                Player.players.get(i).draw();
        }

        controllerListener.poll();

        gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES);
            gl2.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
            gl2.glVertex3d(1, 0, 0);
            gl2.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
            gl2.glVertex3d(0, 1, 0);
            gl2.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
            gl2.glVertex3d(0, 0, 1);
        gl2.glEnd();
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        setSize(Main.frame.screenSize[0], Main.frame.screenSize[1]);
    }
}
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Without any code, it's not easy to answer your question, please edit your post

Comment: This is done, can you help me?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I just set Panel class as a child of GLCanvas class instead of GLJPanel, and then, for a reason I don't understand yet, It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: GLJPanel has an higher memory footprint than JOGL AWT GLCanvas, the former is slower than the latter on some hardware. Anyway, you're currently using an obsolete subversion of JOGL 2, please switch to JOGL 2.3.2. Don't hesitate to ask for help on our official forum.

Comment: By the way, replace "new GLU()" by GLU.createGLU(GL) in order to create a more capable GLU instance and to avoid getting an UnsupportedOperationException in some cases.

Comment: Ok, I understand better. Thanks a lot, I'll apply those advices.